# Python get percentage increase based on datetime columns on previous days

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, percentage

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of increase in a price, based on the price of the previous day and the price of two days before. The problem I'm fancing is that I don't know how to access to the element of two days before properly.

The dataset is the following:

| slug | datetime | price_usd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00 | 29799.079714 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00 | 1823.569357 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00 | 30467.487741 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00 | 1775.07862 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00 | 29704.391357 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00 | 1834.15057 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00 | 29832.914225 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00 | 1801.609446 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00 | 29906.661748 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00 | 1805.204989 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00 | 31364.535502 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00 | 1858.546508 |

The output dataset should be the following.

**increase_24** is percentage increase over the previous day and
**increase_48** is percentage increase over 2 previous days

| slug | datetime | price_usd | %increase_24 | %increase_48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00 | 29799.079714 |  |  |
| ethereum | 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00 | 1823.569357 |  |  |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00 | 30467.487741 | 0.0243 |  |
| ethereum | 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00 | 1775.07862 | -0.0265 |  |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00 | 29704.391357 | -0.0250 | -0.0031 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00 | 1834.15057 | 0.0332 | 0.0058 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00 | 29832.914225 | 0.0043 | -0.0208 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00 | 1801.609446 | -0.0177 | 0.0149 |
| bitcoin | 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00 | 29906.661748 | 0.0024 | 0.0068 |
| ethereum | 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00 | 1805.204989 | 0.0019 | -0.0015 |

I think the solution should be something like that...

```
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df_aux = df.shift(periods=1, freq='D')
pd.concat([df_btc, df_aux],  axis=1)
```

but when I try to concat, python shows me the following error:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Any Idea on How to obtain the 2 columns on the right? (%increase_24 and %increase_48)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby` + `pct_change`

```
g = df.groupby('slug')
df['%increase_24'] = g['price_usd'].pct_change(1)
df['%increase_48'] = g['price_usd'].pct_change(2)
```

---

```
        slug                  datetime     price_usd  %increase_24  %increase_48
0    bitcoin 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00  29799.079714           NaN           NaN
1   ethereum 2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00   1823.569357           NaN           NaN
2    bitcoin 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00  30467.487741      0.022430           NaN
3   ethereum 2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00   1775.078620     -0.026591           NaN
4    bitcoin 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00  29704.391357     -0.025046     -0.003178
5   ethereum 2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00   1834.150570      0.033278      0.005802
6    bitcoin 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00  29832.914225      0.004327     -0.020828
7   ethereum 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00   1801.609446     -0.017742      0.014946
8    bitcoin 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00  29906.661748      0.002472      0.006809
9   ethereum 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00   1805.204989      0.001996     -0.015781
10   bitcoin 2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00  31364.535502      0.048747      0.051340
11  ethereum 2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00   1858.546508      0.029549      0.031603
```

PS: I am assuming the `datetime` values per `slug` are continuous with frequency of `1 days`

Answer (score 1):

Try [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) first with [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df['%increase_24'] = df.groupby('slug')['price_usd'].pct_change(1)
df['%increase_48'] = df.groupby('slug')['price_usd'].pct_change(2)
```

[out]

```
        slug                   datetime     price_usd  %increase_24  %increase_48
0    bitcoin  2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00  29799.079714           NaN           NaN
1   ethereum  2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00   1823.569357           NaN           NaN
2    bitcoin  2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00  30467.487741      0.022430           NaN
3   ethereum  2022-06-02 00:00:00+00:00   1775.078620     -0.026591           NaN
4    bitcoin  2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00  29704.391357     -0.025046     -0.003178
5   ethereum  2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00   1834.150570      0.033278      0.005802
6    bitcoin  2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00  29832.914225      0.004327     -0.020828
7   ethereum  2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00   1801.609446     -0.017742      0.014946
8    bitcoin  2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00  29906.661748      0.002472      0.006809
9   ethereum  2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00   1805.204989      0.001996     -0.015781
10   bitcoin  2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00  31364.535502      0.048747      0.051340
11  ethereum  2022-06-06 00:00:00+00:00   1858.546508      0.029549      0.031603
```